SQLAlchemy and Athena
I am trying to connect to athena database using SQLAlchemy create_engine api. The datasource name is Athena-xxxx, the database name is amazon_security_lake_glue_db_ca_central_1 and the primary workgroup is name security_lake_gen_ai
My connection string is as below:
engine_athena = create_engine(
    "awsathena+rest://@athena.{}.amazonaws.com:443/{}?s3_staging_dir={}".
    format(REGION_NAME, "amazon_security_lake_glue_db_ca_central_1", S3_STAGING_DIR)
)

It fails to connect with below error message:
OperationalError: An error occurred (MetadataException) when calling the ListTableMetadata operation: Database amazon_security_lake_glue_db_ca_central_1 not found. (Service: AmazonDataCatalog; Status Code: 400; Error Code: EntityNotFoundException; Request ID: ad8d4d68-a0b1-459b-81ed-92f928935b2b; Proxy: null)

Is there any way to pass additional information in create_engine api?
Thanks for your help.
Hiren
